# in what = which?

Tags: grammar

> Washington has barred companies worldwide from manufacturing chips for Huawei, the telecoms business, **in what** is a potential death sentence for its affiliate HiSilicon, China’s largest chip designer. The US has also restricted American companies from supplying Semiconductor Manufacturing International Corporation, China’s most advanced chipmaker, with the machines needed for making chips.

What does "in what" mean, can I replace it with "which"?

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/267888/can-anyone-explain-the-use-of-in-what-in-the-following-sentence This link could be useful. I think "in what" means "such a thing", "this circumstance" and you can't substitute it with "which".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Washington has barred companies worldwide from manufacturing chips for Huawei, the telecoms business, **in what** is a potential death sentence for its affiliate HiSilicon, China’s largest chip designer.

"In what" can be understood here as "in a decision that/which", "in a move that", or more generally "in something that".

In your example, you could replace it with "which" without affecting the meaning much if at all.  But in reality "in what" doesn't mean "which".  It means "in something which" or "in something that", which in this context means "in a policy that" or "in a decision that".

Answer (score 1):

The words ***in what*** (or equivalent ***which***<sup>1</sup>; that's just a stylistic choice) here are a syntactic device used to "collapse" two consecutive sentences into one.

The meaning might be easier for non-native speakers if we put a full stop after ***business***, and replace ***in what*** by ***This*** (a pronoun referring back to the preceding sentence in its entirety, ***or*** to the action described by that text; it makes no real difference how you interpret at that level).

> *Washington has [done something]**. This** is a potential death sentence...*

---

<sup>1</sup> Strictly speaking, ***what*** is equivalent to ***something which*** (and either of those can follow ***in*** here). It's also valid to have just ***which*** without ***in***, but you can't do that with ***what***.